# Different Access VBA code results depending on whether breakpoint is set

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an odd circumstance related to an Access form.  I have a parent form (shown in Single Form view) with a subform (shown in Continuous Forms view).  The parent form displays records (one at a time) for each project, and the subform display notes (all of them) for each project.

The notes subform can have dozens or hundreds of records for each project record.  And to make it convenient for the users to just start typing notes into the form right when they pull up a record, I have code in the parent form's on current event that "positions" the records in the subform to show the bottom four existing records and then one record where they can start entering text.  That code looks like the following:

```
Dim mymove As Integer
Dim c As Integer

'' Attempt to scroll down in the CaseNotes subform to a convienent location
'' so that user can read the most recent note and has access to the next
'' blank note
With Me.CaseNotes.Form.Recordset

    ' Load the # of notes for this record
    c = .RecordCount

    ' The display shows only 5 notes.  Otherwise, you have to scroll.
    ' If there are more than 4 notes, we want to display just the last
    ' four and then have a blank line where a new note can be entered.
    ' The following code makes the moves necessary for this.
    If c <= 4 Then mymove = c Else mymove = 4

    If mymove > 0 Then
      .MoveLast
      .Move -mymove
    End If

    'move to new record
    .AddNew

End With
```

This code has worked for a million years, and no problems generally with it.  However, recently we added a combobox control to the parent form that allows users to select a data source for the parent form.  The after update event for that combobox changes the parent form's RecordSource according to the value the user selected.

Once we implemented that, our positioning code no longer works right after you change the data source.  So you choose a new data source, it loads the new data on the parent form and on the subforms, and then the notes subform correctly positions itself (using the code above), but then right before it hands over control to the user, it reverts back to the original (bad) position for the notes.  Not clear why.  The positioning code *is* running (I set a breakpoint and stepped through the code), but it's being undone somehow.

Anyway, to outsmart that, I added some additional code to the combobox's after update event code to re-run the positioning code after the RecordSource is set.  Here's where things get weird.  This code works fine... *as long as I step through it manually*.  If I do that (set a breakpoint and keep hitting F8), then it goes through the positioning code and leaves me right where I want to be.  But if I don't set a breakpoint and just let the code roll on its own, it doesn't work.  It seems to do the positioning, but then it reverts back to the initial (bad) subform position right before it gives me control of the form back.

There seems to be absolutely no difference there.  In one case I step through manually, and in the other case the code just runs by itself.  It should give the same result, I'd think.  Why might this give different results, and what might I do to address this?

I have some general sense that different events are firing depending on whether I set a breakpoint, but not sure where to even start in terms of debugging.  Any help is super appreciated.

I'm running Access 2013 32 bit, on Windows 7, if it's useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create a RecordsetClone using the recordset of the subform

Then after navigating via code inside your cloned recordset, 
set the Bookmark of your subform to equal that of the clone.

e.g.

```
Dim rsClone As Recordset
Dim intMoveBack As Integer
Dim intCount As Integer

Set rsClone = Me.CaseNotes.Form.RecordsetClone
intMoveBack = 4


If Not (rsClone.EOF And rsClone.BOF) Then  'there is at least one record in the subform

    rsClone.MoveLast

    For intCount = 1 To intMoveBack - 1
        If Not (rsClone.BOF) Then
            rsClone.MovePrevious
        End If
    Next

    If rsClone.BOF Then   'we have moved back past the first record, so step forward one
        rsClone.MoveNext
    End If

    Me.CaseNotes.SetFocus   'setfocus to the subform

    With Me.CaseNotes.Form
        .Bookmark = rsClone.Bookmark
        .AnyControlOnYourSubform.SetFocus   'replace this with the name of a control on your subform
        .Recordset.AddNew
    End With

End If
```

Comment: Same exact behavior.  It works if I step through it, but doesn't work if I just let the code run.

Comment: Sounds like there might be another event triggering? 

e.g. the OnCurrent of your subform?   If so, "exit sub" or "exit function" right at the top of the other events VBA code (just add those lines in temporarily, as a test) because the above code quoted above is working fine by itself in the example I mocked up